# Reverse DNS while using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: azure, reverse-dns

I am very much aware that [Reverse DNS is possible on Azure Cloud Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/).  That's not what I'm asking about.  I need to know if it's possible when using Azure Resource Manager.  I've looked around a lot online, and while I've found some (2+ year) old questions about it, I can't find any answers.

Thanks!

**EDIT AFTER:**

I may be getting close. I now have a Resource Group configured, and I've given it a Static IP.  That IP is 40.78.157.234.  However, when I do a reverse lookup on that IP, I only get this:

[image]

I found [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-groups-networking/), which offers a sample of how a Public IP could look in JSON format:

[image]

Mine looks very much like that.  But I still can't do the Reverse Lookup.

Answer (score 2):

In order to register a reverse DNS entry for a Web App, you need to have a forward DNS entry pointing to an IP Address within the same subscription.

This is simply to prove that you have some authority over the domain.

If you need to create the reverse DNS entry at the same time as creating the Web App, then you will need to register a temporary IP Address in Azure for the Web App creation process to look up and verify your ownership of the domain.

In this case you would run something like this

```
 $ip = New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name TestIP1 `
                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName `
                -Location $location -AllocationMethod Static
```

Then to find the IP Address you have just registered run

```
$ip.address
```

On the other hand, if you have already deployed your Web App, you can simply ping it, or run (changing `example` for the actual name of your app) (If the web app is already running, you don't need to register a temporary address)

```
(Resolve-DnsName example.azurewebsites.net).ip4address
```

Either way, you should get something like -

> 12.34.56.78

You can then register this address as an A record in DNS.

You can then register the reverse look up in Azure. For a template you can use

```
    "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
    "dnsSettings": {
        "domainNameLabel": "[variables('PublicDNS2')]",
        "ReverseFqdn": "[concat(parameters('vmName2'), '.', variables('domainname'))]"
    }
```

In Powershell you would use

set-AzureRMWebApp  -ResourceGroupName $AppServiceResourceGroupName 
                    `-Name $AppServiceWebAppName`
                    -HostNames $reverseName

At that point you should have a reverse DNS entry configured.

If this is a new deployment, you would want to point the DNS entry that you pointed to the temporary IP address to the Web App you have just deployed. So again if you run

```
(Resolve-DnsName example.azurewebsites.net).ip4address
```

You can then register that IP Address in DNS and you will have a forward address working as well.

Finally, if you used one, delete the temporary address

```
Remove-AzureRmPublicIpAddress -Name TestIP1 `
         -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Force
```

Comment: Ok, I need to head out.  I will digest this more over on Monday.  Thank you again!

Comment: Michael, I am not using a template. Having a hard time following your instructions just doing this raw in Azure Powershell with no template.

Comment: Let's start with this.  What does "Register the address you get above from $ip.IpAddress in DNS" mean? It's the "Register the address in DNS" that I don't understand.

Comment: Do you mean, for example, log into GoDaddy and register this IP as an A record?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston ok, I'll have a bit of a rewrite

Comment: Thank you!!  Just as an example, I don't follow this:  www IN A 123.45.67.89 ;; $ip.IpAddress address

Comment: Before you start, you need to register a temporary IP Address, you store the object for that in $ip, so the  IP Address you have temporarily reserved is at $ip.address

Comment: Right.  Understood.  That much I followed.  It's after that point where I start to get lost.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston hopefully a little clearer!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve that when you create a new public IP using Azure PowerShell 1.x.

The cmdlet to create a public IP under ARM is [New-AzureRmPublicIpAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt603620.aspx). This includes the "-ReverseFqdn" switch that can be used to set the FQDN.

If using ARM templates, the [property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163590.aspx) to set is: `properties -> dnsSettings -> reverseFqdn`.

Disclaimer: I work for the Azure field team at MS Canada.

Comment: Thank you!  I may have more questions as I dig into this.  I'll post as I go.  MUCH appreciated.

Comment: @ Qualcuno -- can you take a look at my edit? Thank you!